# Relationship between a metric and quantum mechanical matrices

Tags: metric-spaces, quantum-mechanics

Let $ds:=\sigma_x dx+ \sigma_y dy + \sigma_z dz$. Then squaring $ds$, we get

$$
ds^2=\sigma_x^2dx^2+ \sigma_y^2dy^2+\sigma_z^2dz^2 + (\sigma_x\sigma_y+ \sigma_y\sigma_x)dxdy + (\sigma_x\sigma_z+\sigma_z\sigma_x)dxdz+(\sigma_y\sigma_z+\sigma_z\sigma_y)dydz
$$

We get a lot of cross-terms, but if $\sigma_x, \sigma_y $ and $\sigma_z$ are Pauli matrices with these properties:

$$
\sigma_x^2=\sigma_y^2=\sigma_z^2=1\\
\sigma_x\sigma_y=-\sigma_y\sigma_x\\
\sigma_x\sigma_z=-\sigma_z\sigma_x\\
\sigma_z\sigma_y=-\sigma_y\sigma_z
$$

Then, the metric is now the usual Euclidian metric.

$$
ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2
$$

Therefore,

$$
\sigma_x dx+ \sigma_y dy + \sigma_z dz=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}
$$

---

This is not just a fluke result, because one can repeat the same exercise with

$$
ds:=\alpha_x dx+ \alpha_y dy + \alpha_z dz-\alpha_tdt
$$

and, squaring $ds$ one will get

$$
ds^2:=dx^2+ dy^2 + dz^2-dt^2
$$

provided that $\alpha_x,\alpha_y, \alpha_y$ and $\alpha_t$ and the Dirac matrices.

What is the source of this connection between eliminating the cross-terms within metrics and matrices relevant to quantum mechanics?

---

In the case of a generalized metric

$$
ds^2=g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu
$$

with a symmetry requirement $g_{\mu \nu}=g_{\nu \mu}$ (the case of general relativity), the cross terms commute and this seems to be precisely the condition which avoid the need for matrix.

***EDIT***

Thinking about it some more, it seems general relativity does have a matrix-like construction. The matrices must have the following properties:

Start with

$$
ds:=A_xdx+A_ydy+A_zdz+A_tdt
$$

Squaring $ds$ produces a GR compliant tensor if the matrices have these properties:

$$
A_x^2=g_{xx}\\
A_y^2=g_{yy}\\
A_z^2=g_{zz}\\
A_t^2=-g_{tt}\\
A_xA_y=A_xA_y=\frac{1}{2}g_{xy}=\frac{1}{2}g_{yx}\\
A_xA_z=A_xA_z=\frac{1}{2}g_{xz}=\frac{1}{2}g_{zx}\\
A_yA_z=A_zA_y=\frac{1}{2}g_{yz}=\frac{1}{2}g_{zy}\\
A_xA_t=A_tA_x=\frac{1}{2}g_{xt}=\frac{1}{2}g_{tx}\\
A_yA_t=A_tA_y=\frac{1}{2}g_{yt}=\frac{1}{2}g_{ty}\\
A_zA_t=A_tA_z=\frac{1}{2}g_{zt}=\frac{1}{2}g_{tz}
$$

I am not sure if this gives quantum mechanically relevant matrices or not.

But we get

$$
A_xdx+A_ydy+A_zdz+A_tdt:=\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your work with infinitesimals in $\Bbb R^3$ is a special case of $(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{\sigma})\times(\vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma})=(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})I_2+i(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\cdot\vec{\sigma}$; your work in $\Bbb R^4$ follows from an analogous identity with gamma matrices, $\{\not a,\,\not b\}=2a\cdot b$. If you want a connection of such identities to your work with $ds^2$, it's simply that these metrics have the same symmetries, be they rotational or Lorentz, as the matrices you're working with. Hence second-order PDEs such as Laplace's equation $\nabla^2\phi=0$ and the massless Klein-Gordon equation $\square\phi=0$ require cross terms' cancellation if they're to be derived from a first-order PDE such as the Dirac equation, and this is why such equations have to use matrices, spinors etc.